# How do I keep axis tick lines on all my tick with d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a graph where I add custom ticks with tickValues():

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickValues(createTickValuesArray(arr.length))
    .tickFormat(formatAxis);
```

But for some reason the graph show tick lines only up to a certain amount after changing the graph from: http://puu.sh/8wD8e.png to 
http://puu.sh/8wCZ6.png

I don't understand why it won't add the ticks for all axis. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us your code please?

Comment: http://puu.sh/8wDP9.txt My code is here, you should be able to find the axis pretty easily with Ctrl+F, byt searching for "axis". I hope this is enough

Comment: This isn't the first time you're asking a question here. Could you please provide a minimal example that reproduces the problem in something like a jsfiddle please?

Comment: I'm sorry, the thing is, I have a working version here, which is an older version of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/Vanquiza/RBr8h/6/ I can't seem to recreate the problem. I've been looking at both the fiddle code and the puush code for a while and I cannot find any difference with the way I've defined the axis, which is why it's odd to me that the axis tick lines disappear in my code.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem yourself then I don't see how we could figure out what's going on.